# How to make another list of the duplicate entries in existing list using python?

Tags: python, list

I had a list like:

```
l = [[(3,4)], [(3,7)], [(3,8)]]
```

I used the `chain()` function to flat the list, now I have a list like:

```
l2 = [3,4,3,7,3,8]
```

I want to separate the duplicate items into another list:

```
l3 = [3,3,3]
l4 = [4,7,8]
```

I used the `set()` function, but it destroyed the duplicate items and resulted in:

```
l3 = [4,7,8]
```

but I want to obtain both of them separately

Comment: Does the order of items have to be preserved?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'd have to do some kind of count. Using the [`collections.Counter()` class](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) would make that easy:

```
from collections import Counter
counts = Counter(main_list)

duplicate_list, unique_list = [], []
for entry in main_list:
    if counts[entry] > 1:
        duplicate_list.append(entry)
    else:
        unique_list.append(entry)
```

`counts` is a multi-set or bag; a mapping of entry to it's count in `main_list`. The above example preserves the ordering of `main_list`.

Comment: I changed the variable names as `l2` looks like `12` in the font. Also, descriptive variable names are always a Good Thing.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: Thanks; note that I was following the OP names there, making it easier to test out the solution.

Comment: Yes I know, I don't know why people use single letter names, really.

Answer (score 0):

extention to @Martijn Pieters answer, you can use ifilter to filter out those that match the criteria in the lambda expression(first argument in ifilter):

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import ifilter

counts = Counter(l2)    

l3 = list(ifilter(lambda x: counts[x] > 1, l2))
l4 = list(ifilter(lambda x: counts[x] == 1, l2))
```